# What is the name that can be given to the people who are exposed to factory noise?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

What is the name that can be given to the people who are exposed to factory noise or occupational noise?

Comment: Can you give some more context—how you want to use the word, for example?

Comment: The persons who are under the occupational noise

Comment: or to put simply, who are under the effect of something dangerous.

Comment: There is not a name or label for everything under the sun.  *These are factory workers who are **at risk** of having their hearing damaged.*

Comment: In American OSHA lingo, that would be: at-risk workers. The risks are defined separately and there are loads and loads of them.